# Can I get data from an ajax request using a global .ajaxSuccess handler?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've created a global handler for `ajaxSuccess`, but I need to be able to examine the data for each request. Is it possible to access the returned data at this point?

```
jQuery(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event, request, options) {
    // i can has the datas? >^..^<
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works in FF, Chrome, IE 8:

```
jQuery(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event, request, options) {
    if (options.dataType == 'json') {
        var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        // i has the datas!
    }
});
```

Comment: JSON.parse would be better in modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event, request, options, data) {
        console.log(data);
});
```